# React Context - State value is not up-to-date inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following context:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const OtherUsersContext = createContext(null);

export default OtherUsersContext;

export function OtherUsersProvider({ children }) {
  const [otherUsers, setOtherUsers] = useState(new Map([]));

  const addUser = (userId, userData) => {
    setOtherUsers(
      (prevOtherUsers) => new Map([...prevOtherUsers, [userId, userData]])
    );
  };

  const updateUser = (userId, userData, merge = true) => {
    ...
  };

  const getUser = (userId) => otherUsers.get(userId);

  const resetUsers = () => {
    setOtherUsers(new Map([]));
  };

  return (
    <OtherUsersContext.Provider
      value={{
        addUser,
        updateUser,
        getUser,
        resetUsers,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </OtherUsersContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

In my app, when a user signs out, I need to reset this context's map, using the function "resetUsers".

Currently this is working good, but there has no sense to reset the map if it has no values, so I have changed the "resetUsers" function to:

```
const resetUsers = () => {
   if(otherUsers.size) {
      setOtherUsers(new Map([]));
   }
}
```

And, this is not working good, because inside resetUsers, otherUsers.size is always 0. Something which disturbs me because outside the function, the value is the correct one...

```
  ...

  const resetUsers = () => {
    console.log(otherUsers.size); // 0
    setOtherUsers(new Map([]));
  };

  console.log(otherUsers.size); // 5

  return ( ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `functional updates` part of [the hooks docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) says:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState.

So instead of just passing the new value to your setter, you can pass a function that depends on the previous state.

This means that you can do:

```
const resetUsers = () => {
   setOtherUsers(prevOtherUsers => prevOtherUsers.size ? new Map([]): prevOtherUsers);
}
```

Comment: so then setOtherUsers((prevOtherUsers) => { if (prevOtherUsers.size) ... as he was doing in other methods

Comment: @christopherchiche but isn't that the same I have?

Comment: @Raul Oh yes, sorry, I re-wrote the example. 
@VictorMolina yes, To be clear, the `useCallback` you propose is also a great tip!

Answer (score 0):

One tip, if you are not getting the most updated state value inside a function, then wrap it inside an useCallback.

Try this:

```
  const resetUsers = useCallback(() => {
    if (otherUsers.size > 0) {
      console.log(otherUsers.size); // 5
      setOtherUsers(new Map([]));
    }
  }, [otherUsers]);
```